# Converting a sorted dictionary to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, sorteddictionary

I have a program that reads an ASCII file and outputs a text file with each character and the number of times it appears in the file. A sorted dictionary was used in this program but I was wondering if you could instead use an array to store  the characters? The code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ASCII
{
    class CharacterFrequency
    {
        private char ch;
        private int frequency;

        public char Ch
        {
            get { return ch; }
            set { ch = value; }
        }
        public int Frequency
        {
            get { return frequency; }
            set { frequency = value; }
        }


    }

    class Program
    {
        public string InputFileName = "";
        public string OutputFileName = "output.txt";
        public string FilePath = "";

        public static SortedDictionary<char, ulong> Count(string stringToCount)
        {
            SortedDictionary<char, ulong> characterCount = new SortedDictionary<char, ulong>();


            foreach (var character in stringToCount)
            {
                if (!characterCount.ContainsKey(character)) // added character to dictionary if only character is absent in charactercount
                {
                    characterCount.Add(character, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    characterCount[character]++; // increemetned count
                }
            }
            return characterCount;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var inputFileName = Path.Combine(filePath, args[0]);
            var outputFileName = Path.Combine(filePath, args[1]);

            // read data, count chars
            var count = Count(File.ReadAllText(inputFileName));

            // create output content
            var outPut = count.Select(x => $"{x.Key}\t{x.Value}");

            // write it to the output file
            File.WriteAllLines(outputFileName, outPut);

        }
    }
    }
```

In the program class is where the sorted dictionary is. Is there a way to instead use an array instead of a sorted dictionary? What code would be best for doing this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your question, what is your problem with using the dictionary? A dictionary is a collection of key-value-pairs. As such, the key-value-pairs can also be stuffed into an array/list. You could also just put the keys, or just put the values into an array/list. Important to note is that an array has a fixed size with a fixed number of elements. Whereas a list can grow and shrink as you add or remove elements from a list (doing similar things with arrays would be rather cumbersome).

Comment: For this project I am supposed to use an array, instead I used a sorted dictionary (the values weren't supposed to be sorted either.) So I was just wondering if there's a way to store the values in array

Comment: .NET text data types don't use ASCII. (You knew that, right? `String wink = "";`) If you want to read a text file encoded with ASCII, use  `File.ReadAllText(inputFileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII",  EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderExceptionFallback.ExceptionFallback))`. This method ensures that you can read only [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html), which will guard any algorithm you write that makes that assumption and let you know early when the input doesn't follow that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and if its ASCII it will even run faster than using a dictionary without significantly increasing memory usage; simply use a `ulong[127]` array and index into it using the character's value:

```
public static ulong[] Count(string stringToCount)
{
    var counter = new ulong[127];

    foreach (var character in stringToCount)
    {
        counter[(int)character] += 1;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

If you only need to handle printable ASCII characters (value 32 onwards), then you can make the array smaller and use offset 32 to index into it:

```
public static ulong[] CountPrintable(string stringToCount)
{
    var counter = new ulong[95];

    foreach (var character in stringToCount)
    {
        var charValue = (int)character;

        if (charValue > 31)
        {
           counter[charValue - 32] +=1;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

And offset again to print them out:

```
counter.Select((x, i) => $"{(char)(i + 32)}\t{counter[i]}");
```

Comment: I get an Index was outside of bounds of the array error at lines 42 and 55. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Zane, line 42 and 55, you say? Hold on a second, let me look at them ... ;-b I guess it is a rather safe to assume that your text files contains tab characters (or similar), or it could even be that contrary to what you wrote in your question, your text file is _not_ a (pure) ASCII file (in other words, your text file might contain characters that are not ASCII).

Comment: Just use `Char.MaxValue + 1` and remove all the magic numbers and offset calculations. All that's needed is a comment that the program counts UTF-16 code units and if the input is limited to ASCII, it will, by design of Unicode and UTF-16, fulfill the requirements.